# JMeter Throughput Shaping by groovy script

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have Test Plan which include Thread Group, in Thread Group nested 2 samplers: 1 - Dummy Sampler, 2 - JSR223 Sampler.

In Test Plan I declarated variable pacing_seconds with value - 15.
In thread group the loop value is 20.
I need to write groovy script in JSR223 Sampler, which should give me the result 4/min.

I'm new to this, I really need help

Comment: Please show a simple jmeter config file (could be a portion of it) which people can understand what you ask for. Then you might have a helping hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way of limiting your Dummy Sampler to 4 requests/minute is using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/), choose one depending on your future requirements.

If you want the equivalent of LoadRunner's [Pacing](http://loadrunnertips.com/VuGen/loadrunner_pacing_calculation.html) all you need to do in Groovy is:

- Get the Dummy Sampler execution time (it can be done using `ctx.getPreviousResult().getTime()` function where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html))
- Subtract this time from the `pacing_seconds` variable
- Sleep for the "delta"

Example code:

```
def pacing = ((vars.get('pacing_seconds') as int) * 1000) - ctx.getPreviousResult().getTime()
if (pacing > 0) {
    def iPacing = pacing != null ? pacing.intValue() : null
    log.info('About to sleep for ' + iPacing)
    Thread.sleep(iPacing)
}
```

More information: [How to Easily Implement Pacing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-easily-implement-pacing-jmeter/)